# How can I log to a different file depending on its name

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I want to be able to do:

```
// A logger.
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
// Stats logger.
private static final Logger stats = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Stats");
```

Whenever I log to `stats` (`stats.info(...)`) I want the log entries to go to a file called *Stats.log*. Logging to `log` should act normal.

I have (probably wrongly) got the following in `Logback.xml`:

```
A failed config that adds nothing to the question now ... removed.
```

I don't seem to be able to find anything that tells me how to select an appender based on the logger name. There's plenty for choosing based on the log level.

**Added**

This is the configuration I ended up with:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>Log.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>Log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 1MB -->
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- Check on startup too. -->
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <appender name="STATS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>Stats.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>Stats-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 1MB -->
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- Check on startup too. -->
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%level %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

  <logger name="Stats" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STATS" />
  </logger>
</configuration>
```

It works fine - although stats are logged to the normal log file too which I may need to remove with a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the STATS Appender to the Stats Logger nad remove it from the root logger:

```
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

<logger name="Stats">
    <appender-ref ref="STATS" />
</logger>
```

That should do it.

An alternative approach would be to use a [Filter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) on the "STATS" Appender.

A filter implements one method that is called for each LoggingEvent and returns "yes", "no" or "undecided" (which then will execute the next filter in the chain)

Basically you have to attach a filter to your "STATS" appender that says "yes" to all LoggingEvents from your stats logger and "no" to everything else.

Comment: Are you able to post an example of a filter that should stop the stats logging going to the FILE appender? That would make this a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first check if it is not a case issue: STATS vs Stats ...?